# ssl website not working on Windows XP

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, ssl, windows-xp

I have an apache webserver configured for SSL, and a page I want to be reached on that server. I cannot reach that SSL webpage from Windows XP and Inernet Explorer 6-7-8. The same page works well with all browsers in other OSs (included IE) and with other browsers on Windows XP. Other internet SSL websites in XP-IE work great as well.
I tried to run `ssldump` on the server, and the connection get closed during SSL handshake.

```
New TCP connection #1: XP_HOST(62044) <-> WEBSERVER(443)
1 1  0.2040 (0.2040)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.1
        cipher suites
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        compression methods
                  NULL
ERROR: Length mismatch
```

I also tried to force client and server to use a specific SSL version (2 or 3) but neither this seems to work.
I think the problem could be some SSL configuration on apache, but I cannot find my mistake.

This is my SSL configuration about ciphersuites:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
```

If anything else is needed, let me know and I will add it here.

SNI and NameServer are disabled on apache.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try relaxing the SSLCipherSuite? You could also try https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html if your website is internet-facing.

Comment: @remi it doesn' work even with SSLCipherSuite ALL

Comment: Did you try another SSL site with the same IE? Does it load? Have you tried the same XP/IE on another host?

Comment: @remi Other SSL sites work fine on the same IE, and I'm able to reproduce the problem on other hosts as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved.
I found that Windows XP has problems with fragmented SSL/TLS handshake messages. Searching through the Microsoft Knowledge Base, i found that "the Microsoft implementation of the TLS/SSL protocol cannot parse fragmented messages" (see [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2541763/en-us) ).

Microsoft Update KB2541763 (available at the linked page) solves the problem, allowing Windows XP (as well as Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista) to accept fragmented handshake messages from web servers.

Best Regards.

Comment: All links are out of date unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

That OS does not work with SNI, which is required when you want to run multiple SSL VHs on the same IP.

Edit your SSL VirtualHost from `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost IP.Address:443>`, and don't run any other SSL VirtualHosts on that IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, as I wrote also in the question, SNI is already disabled.

Comment: @wizard, See if XP's Internet Options settings has TLS check-marked.

Comment: @wizard, does setting `SSLCipherSuite All` and `SSLProtocol All` make any difference?

Comment: @wizard, so it's just that 1 SSL VH that has this problem, the other SSL VHs do not? You should post the VirtualHost and the .htaccess - as it seems like the problem is specific to it.

Comment: @wizard, I've also seen some firewall s/w, and some network equipment, targeting specific domain-name traffic in-whichever ways, and mess things up.

Comment: there is only this VH on that server, and from the same client machine in which IE doesn't work Firefox works great, so I think a network/firewall problem can also be excluded. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.